# Administrate gem - how to show attribute which target model does not have as column, on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, administrate, rails-administrate

I'm trying to show attributes which a model does not have as column.

For example, I want to show "total_salary" on user index dashboard.
User model's schema is as followings,

```
id int
name string
age int
```

As above, User model does not have column "total_salary".

I changed dashboard page which was generated automatically by administrate gem.

Before

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
 id: Field::Number
 name: Field::String
 age: Field::Number
}

COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = {
 id: Field::Number
 name: Field::String
 age: Field::Number
}
```

After

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
 id: Field::Number
 name: Field::String
 age: Field::Number
 total_salary: Field::Number # Changed 
}

COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = {
 id: Field::Number
 name: Field::String
 age: Field::Number
 total_salary: Field::Number # Changed 
}
```

Where to add logic to calculate each user's total salary?
(If file witch already exists, please teach me the file path. If I have to create new file or folder, please teach me where to make.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a custom field since `total_salary` doesn't map to a column. To do this you need to add a class to calculate it:

```
# app/fields/total_salary_field.rb

class TotalSalaryField < Administrate::Field::Base
  def total_salary
    # Perform calculation here
  end
end
```

and then do:

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  ...,
  total_salary: TotalSalaryField,
  ...
}
```

Here's a link to the documentation for custom field types: https://administrate-demo-prerelease.herokuapp.com/adding_custom_field_types